# Invalid Binary on Itunes in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

I just try to upload a new version of my app with some bugs fixed.

I check all the icon files & version history are set in plist file.

**App is passed the Validation & shows me as submitted & also shows me `Upload received`.**

**But after 2 minutes it shows me `Invalid Binary`.**

I can't able to find the problem.
Help me to solve this.

Thank you,

Comment: We faced similar issue and probable workaround is, Please check iCloud is enabled in app id turn it off. Also check other unnecessary options like game center. Check mail also it may have indication or exact reason for rejection.

Comment: Check Your Mail box is there any email from `Apple` related this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

First Please Check Your Email Account `(Developer ID)` Email Address. In My Case i Got email form `Apple` with diagnose information. 
Here is the All Details In the Email.

```
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement, the first value in the array must consist of the prefix provided by Apple in the provisioning profile followed by a bundle identifier suffix. The bundle identifier must match the bundle identifier for one of your apps or another app that you are permitted to use as the iCloud container identifier.

Specifically, value "KD8JU7654H.*" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in ProductName is not supported.

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported.

Specifically, value "KD8JU7654H.*" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier" in ProductName is not supported.
```

In another option `Revoked` all of your `certificates`. then add new `app id` and `provisioning` then try to `upload application.`

Comment: You can also remove unwanted frameworks from other linker flags, because may that frameworks name can contain UDID/uniqueIdentifier .